# How would you return a value from an individual field in a custom widget?

Tags: widgets

I have built a handful of custom widgets on my site. In the main these are just fine how they are. But occassionally I also want to be able to use a field individually rather than the whole widget.

For example I have an address widget which has five fields: 'Street', 'Locality', 'Region', 'PostCode', and 'Country'.

The single address that is output will be used several locations on the site, but occasionally I just need the value from one field at a time eg: just the 'PostCode'.

Is there a way to extract individual field data from a widget?

As I assume is pretty standard the display for my widget is handled like so:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    extract( $args );

    $street      = $instance['street'];
    $locality    = $instance['locality'];
    $region      = $instance['region'];
    $postCode    = $instance['postCode'];
    $country     = $instance['country'];

    echo $before_widget;

   // Display the widget
   if ( $street ) {
        echo $street . '<br>';
    }
    if ( $locality ) {
        echo $locality . ',<br>';
    }
    if ( $region ) {
        echo $region . ',<br>';
    }
    if ( $postCode ) {
        echo $postCode . '<br>';
    }
    if ( $country ) {
        echo $country;
    }

    echo $after_widget;
}
```

It is used in a sidebar call 'address' and currently I output that to the page like so:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'address' ) ) { dynamic_sidebar( 'address' ); }
```

My assumtion is that either an edit to the latter would do what I'm after, or I can somehow access the individual fields of the widget in the sidebar seperately. Eiter way (if any assumption is correct) I need some direction as to how to do this.
I will need to usethis same data in several locations, just on occassion not all of it.

Comment: Yes, of course. You'd be outputting the fields individually anyway, so just don't output the ones you don't want. If that doesn't make sense then you're going to need to elaborate.

Comment: @JacobPeattie That is good news!. Perhaps I've misunderstood how widgets worked, but I assumed that widget fields were output to the page as a group. Hopefully this means you can use the same widget data in multiple ways. I've made an  edit to my question to clarify where I am at this point.